# How to correct pytest "NameError: name * is not defined for parallel source and test folders

Tags: python, pytest

I'm running pytest platform win32 -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1

My folder structure follows https://docs.pytest.org/en/5.3.5/goodpractices.html

```
C:\Users\auser\Desktop\My-App\
    setup.py
    tests\
        test_Receiver.py
        test_Sender.py
    appscr\
        __init__.py
        Receiver.py
        Sender.py
    appscr.egg-info\
```

The two app modules are similar

```
Sender.py
    class MyChannel:
    ...
        def openChannel(self):
    ...
    def getOptions():
    ...
```

Both files run in IDLE without failures and I had the tests working before refactoring the folders. I'm getting pytest errors which seem to indicate pytest can't find the source files and then match test code with functions. I've added/removed `import` for the modules and packages to the test modules - no difference. I'm stumped as to how to fix this.

Here's one error for a fixture to instantiate an object to be tested

```
    ___ ERROR at setup of test_ctor 
    @pytest.fixture
    def newObject():
    #   instantiate new Object Under Test
    >       objectUnderTest = MyChannel(1,2,3)
    E       NameError: name 'MyChannel' is not defined
    tests\test_Reciever.py:37: NameError
```

Here's a second error for a function

```
    ____ test_getOptions _______________________________________________
    def test_getOptions():
    >       getOptions()
    E       NameError: name 'getOptions' is not defined
    tests\test_Receiver.py:29: NameError
```

Comment: How are you running `pytest`? Do you use `python -m pytest`? Also, the `NameError` indicates that you didn't import your package in the test in these cases - how did you import your class /function?

Comment: I run pytest from C:\Users\auser\Desktop\My-App\.  Same results if run python -m pytest.

Comment: Both test_* files **import  My-App**

Comment: Although the doc has a very detail explanation of how pytest searches for test files, I cannot find a clear explanation of how it locates files for the item under test, given the noted structure. There are apparently unstated assumptions.

Comment: If you just `import My-App`, you have to use `My-App.Sender.MyChannel` and `My-App.Sender.getOptions()`

Comment: I added `from My-App.Sender import *`.  This cured the not found errors, and I can reference the target functions without the prefix.